# $a\equiv 1 \pmod {p^k} \iff a^p \equiv 1 \pmod{p^{k+1}}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to prove the following statement, from my Elementary NT book: $a\equiv 1 \pmod {p^k} \iff a^p \equiv 1 \pmod{p^{k+1}}$.

I'm really lost on how to show this. All I have so far is reducing it to $p^k|a-1 \iff p^{k+1}|a^p-1$. So we need to show $p^{k+1}|p(a-1)$? But I'm really not sure what I can do here.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Try expanding the right side using the Binomial theorem of $a^p = (1 + np^k)^p$. Also, the [Lifting-the-exponent lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifting-the-exponent_lemma) may help.

Comment: Write $a$ as $1+mp^k$ and use binomial theorem for the forward implication. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4181854/930909) for the backwards implication.

Comment: See also [Congruence of integers and primitive roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3233174/congruence-of-integers-and-primitive-roots).

Answer (score 1):

$$a^k\equiv 1 \pmod {p^k} $$
$$\implies\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}a^k\equiv\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}1\equiv p\pmod{p^k}$$
$$\implies p\mid \sum_{k=0}^{p-1}a^k-p$$
$$\implies p\mid\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}a^k$$
$\displaystyle a^p-1=(a-1)\left(\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}a^k\right)$.
$p^k$ divides $(a-1)$ and $p$ divides $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}a^k$.

Therefore $p^{k+1}\mid a^p-1$